MiniflareCoreError [ERR_RUNTIME_FAILURE]: The Workers runtime failed to start. There is likely additional logging output above
I am getting this error while using npm run dev:
        ^

MiniflareCoreError [ERR_RUNTIME_FAILURE]: The Workers runtime failed to start. There is likely additional logging output above.

How do I solve this error?

You may want to read [ask]

Same situation, specifically with 3.63.1.
The problem goes away if I revert to 3.57.1.
npm install wrangler@3.57.1

That might work as a temporary solution for you.
